# From yeomon generator to production

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, yeoman

I've been using 'yo express' command and choose MVC , jade , grunt ....
Everything is working fine and now I'm managing to deploy my app.
Now I only know two commands to start my app

1. grunt
2. node app.js

If I run "grunt" command on my production server , it will enable livereload server , which is good for development but not production.

I think maybe grunt can help me to do optimization but I couldn't find it. I saw webpack is a good choice but it's too difficult for me to use it.

Is there any way to do optimization ( like compress js css ) or other tasks for deploying on my 'yo express' generated app?

Thanks.

Comment: Grunt comprises of number of tasks. You can configure grunt by eliminating `livereload` for production environment. Look for gruntfile.js in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally there is no need to minify your server side js file because this only reduced the loading time for the browser which here isn't the case. To run nodejs in productin you could look at a a process manager like [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2). To build your client side files for production you might have to extend your grunt setup by yourself or use a second yo generator for your frontend part of the application.

Comment: I got it.
Use grunt or gulp build compressed js , css files... and monitor process it with pm2.

Cheers , petecoop

Comment: no worries, if you want to can you please accept my answer? cheers